# Textwatcher giving Stackoverflow error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext, stack-overflow

i am making a length converter which uses TextWatcher.
the shortened code is

```
 v1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                val1=Double.parseDouble(v1.getText().toString()); 
                val2=InchToCm(val1); 
                val3=InchToMl(val1);
                val4=InchToKm(val1);
                val5=InchToM(val1);
                val6=InchToY(val1);
                val7=InchToFt(val1);
                val8=InchToLg(val1);
                val9=InchToLgn(val1);
                val11=InchTomm(val1);
                val12=InchToNm(val1);


                v2. setText(Double.toString(val2)); 
                v3. setText(Double.toString(val3)); 
                v4. setText(Double.toString(val4)); 
                v5. setText(Double.toString(val5)); 
                v6. setText(Double.toString(val6)); 
                v7. setText(Double.toString(val7)); 
                v8. setText(Double.toString(val8));
                v9. setText(Double.toString(val9)); 
                v11. setText(Double.toString(val11)); 
                v12. setText(Double.toString(val12));

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
     v2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                val2=Double.parseDouble(v2.getText().toString()); 
                val1=CmToInch(val2);
                val3=CmToMl(val2);
                val4=CmToKm(val2);
                val5=CmToM(val2);
                val6=CmToY(val2);
                val7=CmToFt(val2);
                val8=CmToLg(val2);
                val9=CmToLgn(val2);
                val11=CmTomm(val2);
                val12=CmToNm(val2);

                v1. setText(Double.toString(val1)); 
                v3. setText(Double.toString(val3)); 
                v4. setText(Double.toString(val4)); 
                v5. setText(Double.toString(val5)); 
                v6. setText(Double.toString(val6)); 
                v7. setText(Double.toString(val7)); 
                v8. setText(Double.toString(val8));
                v9. setText(Double.toString(val9)); 
                v11. setText(Double.toString(val11)); 
                v12. setText(Double.toString(val12));

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

i am getting a stackoverflow error.if i remove the textwatcher code for v2 completely.the text watcher for v1 works perfectly..
i just want all my edittext to work with textwatcher.
what am i missing?and what should i change?

heres the logcat

```
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377): java.lang.StackOverflowError
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at           android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:77)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377): android.text.TextUtils.indexOf(TextUtils.java:110)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at     android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:182)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:170)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6078)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5976)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6515)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3787)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3645)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at com.tdx.simplelegthconverter.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:55)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7338)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3790)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3645)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
08-20 20:31:28.122: E/AndroidRuntime(30377):    at   com.tdx.simplelegthconverter.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:95)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are creating an infinite loop of Text Changes between v1 and v2.

Whenever you edit something in v1, it's `TextWatcher` sets the text of v2 which in turn triggers the `onTextChanged()` of your v2's `TextWatcher`. Now, v2's `TextWatcher` sets text of v1 (which triggers the `onTextChanged()` of your v1 again). This is creating a never-ending loop and you are getting the StackOverflow exception.

You have to change the flow of your code.

EDIT:
I am showing an example, how to get rid of the StackOverflow error for two EditText fields. You can follow the similar coding for as many EditTexts as you want.

First of all, you can extend the TextWatcher like this (This will help you to keep your code organized. And, you can use this same TextWatcher for all your EditTexts):

```
class MyInputWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private EditText et;

        private MyInputWatcher(EditText editText) {
            et = editText;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            switch (et.getId()) {
            case R.id.editText1: {
                v2.removeTextChangedListener(watcher2);
                v2.setText(s);// set whatever text you want to set in editText2
                v2.addTextChangedListener(watcher2);
                //add the above 3 lines of code for other EditTexts, too (if any)
                break;
            }
            case R.id.editText2: {
                v1.removeTextChangedListener(watcher1);
                v1.setText(s); // set whatever text you want to set in editText1
                v1.addTextChangedListener(watcher1);

                break;
            }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    }
```

The trick is to remove the onTextChangeListeners before you call `setText()`. And, then add them back after you are done with setting text.

Declare these member variables:

```
private EditText v1, v2;
private MyInputWatcher watcher1, watcher2;
```

Now, in the onCreate() method, implement this:

```
v1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
v2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

watcher1 = new MyInputWatcher(v1);
watcher2 = new MyInputWatcher(v2);

v1.addTextChangedListener(watcher1);
v2.addTextChangedListener(watcher2);
```

For your convenience, the whole Activity class looks like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText v1, v2;
    private MyInputWatcher watcher1, watcher2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        v1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        v2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        watcher1 = new MyInputWatcher(v1);
        watcher2 = new MyInputWatcher(v2);

        v1.addTextChangedListener(watcher1);
        v2.addTextChangedListener(watcher2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class MyInputWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private EditText et;

        private MyInputWatcher(EditText editText) {
            et = editText;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            switch (et.getId()) {
            case R.id.editText1: {
                v2.removeTextChangedListener(watcher2);
                v2.setText(s);// set whatever text you want to set in editText2
                v2.addTextChangedListener(watcher2);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.editText2: {
                v1.removeTextChangedListener(watcher1);
                v1.setText(s); // set whatever text you want to set in editText1
                v1.addTextChangedListener(watcher1);

                break;
            }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To break the apparent looping situation, you have to get rid of one of those `v2.setText(Double.toString(val2));` of v1's textWatcher or `v1.setText(Double.toString(val1));` in v2's TextWatcher. You can consider using flags to keep records of which EditText should be updated and which shouldn't be.

Comment: ok i removed v2.setText From v1's Textwatcher.it works.so similarly i have to define textwatchers for every edittext accordingly.what about the missing v2 in v1's textwatcher?also i get a fc when i backspace any value

Comment: Please see the edit. The example code is attached now. It worked fine for me with two EditTexts.

Comment: amazing code.works perfectly except for the fc when i press backspace to delete any inputted number..the app fc when i try to delete the last number.

Comment: Just play with the code. That's the basic example code I provided. Modify the code according to your need. If you think it solved what you asked for, please accept the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not do setText inside onTextChanged(),it is causing recursion.

You can try the following:
Set a boolean variable when you do setText from inside the onTextChange(). This boolean variable will help to identify that onTextChange was called because text was change programmatically and not by the user,thus avoiding recursion

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                      if(isTextChangedByUser){
                          //calculate and set different values only when user has changed       values
                           editext.setText("programmatically setting the text,change the flag")
                           isTextChangedByUser=false;
                       }else{
                           //to avoid recursion
                            return;
                       }
        }
```

Second time when `onTextChanged` is called it will simply return since `isTextChangeByUser` flag is false.In this manner we will avoid recursion.

Alternatively,to make the implementation more simple you can put a "calculate" button next to each editext.You will only start calculation when the user presses this button and not when text changes.

Comment: where am i supposed to use it then?

Comment: can you show an example using my code please?i earlier had put the convert button,but i wanna learn textwatcher and not use onClick method

Comment: How do you detect whether the text is changed by the user or by your code? If you set the text by calling the `setText()` (programmatically - as you said, it still triggers the `onTextChanged()`). That's the actual problem, isn't it? `onTextChanged()` is fired regardless of the source (user interaction or programmatical) of the text change.

Comment: Instead, some tricks can be used if you implement anything like the onKeyListener to identify the interaction of the user. But again, onKeyListener may not respond to actions from Soft Keyboard.

Comment: Still doesn't solve the actual problem. Your solution failed to show how to utilize your proposed flag variable to distinguish the source of the text change event. You better come up with a comprehensive solution.

Comment: @HungryCoder when you call setText() on any edittext that means that you are setting the text programmatically..you need to set the flag here..

Comment: Yeah, I got that part. But, how does that solve the problem? IMHO, it is not solving the main problem at all. Why you are trying to blabber the same thing again and again rather than providing a comprehensive solution?