# EditText aftertextchanged throw StackOverflowError

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have an `EditText` and a `TextWatcher.` while testing in our test device we never found StackOverflowError, but once we published our app in Google Play Store, we are getting StackOverflowError issue for some user. Why this is happening, I go through some of link but not got the perfect answer. Is anything need to be done in my code.

Skeleton of my code:

```
weightEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            }           
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                m_currentWeight = weightEditText.getText().toString();              
            }           
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                if(!weightEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\\.[0-9]{0,2}?)?)?$");

                    Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(s.toString());
                    if (!matcher.find()) {
                        weightEditText.setText(m_currentWeight);
                        weightEditText.setSelection(weightEditText.getText().length());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you're setting the TextView's text from within the same TextView's TextWatcher, then you've set up an infinite loop, which is causing a StackOverflowException

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textwatcher giving Stackoverflow error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407959/textwatcher-giving-stackoverflow-error)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `setText()` inside of the text watcher which will produce an infinite loop. You can use a flag variable to avoid this.

1. `status` variable  is set as `false` by defaut.
2. `status` variable indicates whether the TextChange is made by App itself or by the user himself. if it is `true`, then the TextChange is made by App itself and vice versa.

Try this code. Cheers ! :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 boolean status=false;//global variable

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        weightEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
            {           
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
                }           
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    m_currentWeight = weightEditText.getText().toString();              
                }           
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                {
                    if(status){
                    status=false;
                     return;
                     }else{
                      status=true;
                      if(!weightEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\\.[0-9]{0,2}?)?)?$");

                        Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(s.toString());
                        if (!matcher.find()) {
                            weightEditText.setText(m_currentWeight);
                            weightEditText.setSelection(weightEditText.getText().length());
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
            }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How it will solve the issue. Is boolean status=false; will be a global variable, when it need to be initialize again

Comment: ya. it should be global

Comment: Can u explain how this will prevent form stackoverflow error

Comment: Still not solved my issue, show stackoverflow issue again

Answer (score 0):

To avoid recursion here you need to unregister your textWatcher before setting the text and then reregister it.

Declare the TextWatcher outside the addTextChangedListener(...) method. Then you can do weightEditText.removeTextChangedListener(mWatcher) and weightEditText.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher)

Comment: How to achieve that?

Comment: Declare the TextWatcher outside the addTextChangedListener(...) method. Then you can do weightEditText.removeTextChangedListener(mWatcher) and weightEditText.addTextChangedListener(mWatcher)