# addTextChangedListener throws StackOverflow Error

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
areasqm.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(areasqm.getText().toString());
        areaha.setText(String.valueOf(val/10000));
    }      
});

areaha.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(areaha.getText().toString());
        areasqm.setText(String.valueOf(val*10000));
    }      
});
```

Whenever I typed a value in one of the EditTexts, my application will crash and throws **java.lang.StackOverflowError**.

**Why? How to fix this one?**

Comment: first check value is null or not if (s.length() == 0) {// you code}

Comment: try to set value in afterTextChanged() instead of onTextChanged()

Comment: You are doing a recursive call there. (textChanged -> setText -> textChanged...)

Comment: @Mehta, its not working!

Comment: @EthylCasin Try with my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause is: when you call `areaha.setText(String.valueOf(val/10000));` the **TextChangedListener** of **areaha** is triggered and calls `areasqm.setText(String.valueOf(val*10000));`, so the **TextChangedListener** of **areasqm** is triggered too and calls `areaha.setText(String.valueOf(val/10000));`. So you have eternal loop and as result this **java.lang.StackOverflowError.**.

You can try something like this.

```
private TextWatcher areasmlWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(areasqm.getText().toString());
        areaha.removeTextChangedListener(areahaWatcher);
        areaha.setText(String.valueOf(val / 10000));
        areaha.addTextChangedListener(areahaWatcher);
    }
};

private TextWatcher areahaWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(areaha.getText().toString());
        areasqm.removeTextChangedListener(areasmlWatcher);
        areasqm.setText(String.valueOf(val*10000));
        areasqm.addTextChangedListener(areasmlWatcher);
    }
};

private void someMethod() {
    areasqm.addTextChangedListener(areasmlWatcher);
    areaha.addTextChangedListener(areahaWatcher);
}
```

Comment: you should change logic of your code. I don't know what you want in result.

Comment: You could set the edited value to another `TextView` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You Got this error due to as per your code it is in infinite loop both edit text continuous update each other value

Comment: so how do i fix it?

Comment: Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407959/textwatcher-giving-stackoverflow-error

Comment: try to add addTextChangedListener on focus gain and remove it when edit text lost focus

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the **java.lang.StackOverflowError** is due to the recursive call of `onTextChanged()` and `setText()` when you change the edit text.

Since you are trying to multiply the value entered with 1000, what I can think of doing is:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    double val = Double.parseDouble(areaha.getText().toString());
    if (val % 10000 != 0) {
        val = val * 10000;
        areasqm.setText(String.valueOf(val));
    }
}
```

But bear in mind that this is with condition that your value_entered is int, not double or float (decimal).

Hope this helps;)

Comment: Still not working.. it throws StackOverflow Error, but thank you anyway. I appreciate it!